# What is this effect (Motion Trails) called and how can i create it?

Tags: video

I'm new to adobe premiere pro and I don't know what this effect called and how to create it.
[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/clip/UgkxeY76-qR74J6ueJ2LhYoaCpiGcbHH288O)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s a motion trail. You can use After Effects to create one using the Echo effect. Here’s a tutorial that explains how to do it:

Answer (score 0):

I would call it "Onion Skin" Effect.

I suppose there is some plugin for some software like after effects, premiere, DavinciResolve, or something.

A way to manually do it would be layering copies of the same video, let's say 10 copies and de-synchronize them by a couple of frames incrementally.

Define also incremental or decrimental values for the opacity.